# Public key authentication problems on OSX

Tags: macos, ssh

I am trying to set up public key authentication on a Mac OSX server, but to no avail (I'm able to log in with my password fine). I've tried several suggestions in answers to other questions, but so far haven't found the problem. I'm posting a slew of debug data that I accumulated going through potential solutions to give you an idea of what I've already tried and what my system configurations are.

### System info

#### Server

```
server:~ admin$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
server:~ admin$ uname -a
Darwin server 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

#### Client

```
user@local ~ $ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
user@local ~ $ uname -a
Linux local 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### File permissions

#### Server

```
server:~ admin$ ls -la
drwx------   4 admin  staff    136 Jul 13 14:43 .ssh
server:~ admin$ ls -la .ssh
-rw-------   1 admin  staff   895 Jul 13 15:32 authorized_keys
server:~ admin$ ls -l ..
drwxr-x---+ 23 admin          staff  782 Jul 13 17:40 admin
```

#### Client

```
user@local ~ $ ls -la .ssh
-rw-------  1 user user  444 Jul 13 14:38 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   95 Jul 13 14:38 id_ed25519.pub
-rw-------  1 user user 3326 Aug 14  2012 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  800 Feb 18  2014 id_rsa.pub
```

### Copying keys over

I originally manually copied my public keys over with `scp` and appended them to `authorized_keys` with `cat`, but I also tried `ssh-copy-id`:

```
user@local ~/.ssh $ ssh-copy-id admin@server
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Password:

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'admin@server'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

Public key authentication doesn't work after this, and if I run `ssh-copy-id` again I get exactly the same output.

### Uncommented lines in `sshd_config`

```
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV

# The following three lines were originally commented out, but I uncommented
# them since I wasn't sure what the defaults were.
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

PasswordAuthentication yes
KerberosAuthentication yes
KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
KerberosTicketCleanup yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
GSSAPIKeyExchange no
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

### Running `sshd` in debug

#### Server

```
server:~ admin$ sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -p 2222 -d
Password:
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.2p1
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='2222'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='-d'
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 2222.
debug1: fd 5 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from local port 43965
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: privsep_preauth: successfully loaded Seatbelt profile for unprivileged child
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 75/75
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: KEX done
debug1: userauth-request for user admin service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug1: PAM: initializing for "admin"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "local"
Failed none for admin from local port 43965 ssh2
debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 3
debug1: userauth-request for user admin service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
userauth_pubkey: unsupported public key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: userauth-request for user admin service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 501/20 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /Users/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 501/20 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /Users/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for admin from local port 43965 ssh2
debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 6
debug1: userauth-request for user admin service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive
debug1: attempt 3 failures 2
debug1: keyboard-interactive devs 
debug1: auth2_challenge: user=admin devs=
debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices 'pam'
debug1: auth2_challenge_start: trying authentication method 'pam'
Postponed keyboard-interactive for admin from local port 43965 ssh2
debug1: do_pam_account: called
debug1: PAM: num PAM env strings 1
Postponed keyboard-interactive/pam for admin from local port 43965 ssh2
debug1: do_pam_account: called
Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for admin from local port 43965 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: admin has been authenticated by privileged process
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 501/20 (e=0/0)
debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
User child is on pid 48532
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 501/20
debug1: privsep_postauth: successfully loaded Seatbelt profile for unprivileged child
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 1048576 max 16384
debug1: input_session_request
debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_open: channel 0
debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request pty-req reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
debug1: Allocating pty.
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/ttys003
debug1: Ignoring unsupported tty mode opcode 37 (0x25)
debug1: Ignoring unsupported tty mode opcode 52 (0x34)
debug1: Ignoring unsupported tty mode opcode 71 (0x47)
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request shell reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req shell
debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
```

#### Client

```
user@local ~ $ ssh -vvv -l admin -p 2222 server
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to server [server] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 4
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.2 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [server]:2222
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[server]:2222" from file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1548/3072
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA bd:70:7f:7c:fc:b1:6d:5d:83:86:05:6b:e2:51:5a:a0
debug3: put_host_port: [server]:2222
debug3: put_host_port: [server]:2222
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[server]:2222" from file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[server]:2222" from file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "server" from file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "server" from file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'server' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug2: bits set: 1511/3072
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x************),
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering ED25519 public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 7a:2f:1b:10:60:e1:c7:f3:f1:67:5e:5d:30:f8:b1:fe
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 32 (len 24 padlen 8 extra_pad 64)
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 0
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 10 padlen 6 extra_pad 64)
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to server ([server]:2222).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env COMP_WORDBREAKS
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_COOKIE
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env DEFAULTS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env GDM_XSERVER_LOCATION
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env IPYTHONDIR
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_PID
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env PYTHONSTARTUP
debug3: Ignored env MANDATORY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env QMAKESPEC
debug3: Ignored env MDM_XSERVER_LOCATION
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env PYTHONPATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env MDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAIN
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env MDM_LANG
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAINDIR
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

### Summary

I can't make sense of the debug messages, and rather than spend another entire afternoon trying to figure it out on my own I thought I'd see if any solutions presented themselves to someone here.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from `ssh-copy-id` indicates it copied the public key file for /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa. [The ssh-copy-id source code](https://github.com/andrewpile/ssh-copy-id/blob/master/ssh-copy-id) indicates that it would have gotten this public key from the id_rsa.pub file.

The client debug output shows that it offered two keys to the server, id_ed25519 and id_rsa. The server didn't accept either one.

```
debug1: Offering ED25519 public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
[...]
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
[...]
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
```

The ssh server log shows that it doesn't support id_ed25519 keys. For id_rsa, it read through authorized_keys but ultimately didn't find a match:

```
debug1: userauth-request for user admin service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
userauth_pubkey: unsupported public key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: userauth-request for user admin service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1
[...]
debug1: trying public key file /Users/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
[...]
Failed publickey for admin from local port 43965 ssh2
```

So, you're apparently using the right passphrase for the key. And neither the client nor server had any complaints about permissions for the relevant files. Yet, the server isn't accepting id_rsa despite the fact that ssh-copy-id supposedly copied the id_rsa public key into authorized_keys.

My guess is that you're dealing with one of the following:

1. The `id_rsa.pub` file on the client is corrupt, or doesn't actually contain the public key for the `id_rsa` file.
2. Alternately, the `authorized_keys` file on the server is malformed or corrupt in some way that is preventing the server from parsing it properly.

I'd start by checking the authorized_keys file. It should be a text file with one long line per key. [The sshd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd) describes the file format in more detail. I suggest you delete any lines from this file referencing the id_rsa key that you're using here. And make sure there's a newline at the end of the last line of the file.

Then, on the client, run this:

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa > id_rsa.pub
```

This will re-extract the public key from id_rsa into id_rsa.pub.

Now rerun ssh-copy-id and see if things work better.

Comment: That did the trick. My `.pub` file was in a multiline format, so re-extracting the key changed that. Then after cleaning up the `authorized_keys` file on the server and rerunning `ssh-copy-id` I was able to log on with my key. Thanks.